# How to access value of parent and child both class from pojo using databinding android

Tags: android, json, parent-child, android-databinding, pojo

My respone of pojo class is like:

```
{
    "data": {
        "first_name": "test",
        "last_name": "test123",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "user_id": "11"
    },
    "message": "login successfully.",
    "status": "success."
}
```

and i want access both parent and child class like message and email from above response. How can i get using single pojo..?
 Here i am facing null pointer exception.

My code is:

```
<data>
    <variable name="MyParent"
        type="com.package.ParentModel"/>

</data>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="@={MyParent.data.email}"
    android:id="@+id/et_email"/>
```

how can get property of parent and child both class of same pojo..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it. Strange! It was working fine. I am posting sample code here, you have to match & find issue your own.

**activity_sample.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <data>

        <variable
            name="response"
            type="com.innovanathinklabs.sample.data.Response" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        ...
        >

        <EditText
              ...
              android:text="@={response.data.email}" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

**Response.java** (parent model)

```
public class Response extends BaseObservable {
    private Data data;
    private String message;
    private String status;

    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
}
```

**Data.java** (child model)

```
public class Data extends BaseObservable {
    private String userId;
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private String email;

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
}
```

**ActivitySample.java**

```
public class ActivitySample extends AppCompatActivity {
    ActivitySampleBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_sample);

        // make dummy response data
        Response response = new Response();
        Data data = new Data();
        data.setEmail("khermaj@gmail.com");
        response.setData(data);

        // pass dummy data in layout
        binding.setResponse(response);
    }
}
```

***Things to check :**

1. Check your model should extend `BaseObservable` to use [two-way data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way). Or you can use [ObservableField](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability) too.
2. variable names should start from lower letter. Must check [Java Naming Convensions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/). You have taken `variable name="MyParent"`
3. You will get `NullPointerException` if you have not passed model to Layout. Like I did `binding.setResponse(response);` in `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this model class. It will help you.

```
public class ParentModel {
private String name;
private ChildModel childModel;

public ParentModel(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    childModel=new ChildModel();
    childModel.setName("Apple");

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public ChildModel getChildModel() {
    return childModel;
}

public void setChildModel(ChildModel childModel) {
    this.childModel = childModel;
}

public  class ChildModel {
    public String name ;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
  }
}
```